# A group-theoretical analogous of Temperley-Lieb-Jones subfactor planar algebras

Tags: finite-groups, oa.operator-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, subfactors, planar-algebras

The Temperley-Lieb-Jones subfactor planar algebra $\mathcal{TLJ}_{\delta}$ admits the following properties:

- maximal,
- it exists for every possible index, i.e. $\delta^2 \in \{4cos^2(\pi/n) \ | \ n \le 3\} \cup [4, \infty]$,
- for any subfactor planar algebra $\mathcal{P}$ of index $\delta^2$, there is a unital embedding $\mathcal{TLJ}_{\delta} \hookrightarrow_u \mathcal{P}$.
  ($u$ for unital)

It is the only (family of irreducible) subfactor planar algebra(s) to satisfy all the above properties.

The inclusion $S_{n-1} \subset S_n$ is a kind of group-theoretical analogous because of its properties:

- (core-free) maximal,
- it exists for every possible index, i.e. $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\ge 1}$,

let $\mathcal{PS}_n$ be the (irreducible) group-subgroup subfactor planar algebra $\mathcal{P}(S_{n-1} \subset S_n)$,

- $\mathcal{PS}_n$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{TLJ}_{n^{1/2}}$ for $n \le 3$.

It is the only (family of) core-free inclusion(s) of groups to satisfy the above three properties.

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ a (core-free) subgroup of index $n$.
**Question**: Is there a unital embedding $\mathcal{PS}_n \hookrightarrow_u \mathcal{P}(H \subset G)$?
If so, what about the converse?

More generally, let $G_i$ be a finite group and $H_i$ a (core-free) subgroup of index $n$ with $i=1,2$.
**Extended question**: What is the group-theoretical reformulation for the following property? $$\mathcal{P}(H_1 \subset G_1) \hookrightarrow_u \mathcal{P}(H_2 \subset G_2).$$

*Remark*: the group-theoretical reformulation for isomorphism is known ([MR1920326](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1920326), pointed out in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/136085/34538) of Dave Penneys), let call it *subfactor equivalence of inclusions*.

Let $\mathcal{PA}_n$ be the group-subgroup subfactor planar algebra $\mathcal{P}(A_{n-1} \subset A_n)$, and $G,H$ as above. 
*Alternating question*: Is it true that $\mathcal{PA}_n \hookrightarrow_u \mathcal{P}(H \subset G)$ iff $G \hookrightarrow A_n$?

*General knowledge*: A number $n$ is called *insipid* if the groups having a core-free maximal subgroup of index $n$ are exactly $A_n$ and $S_n$. There is an OEIS enter for these numbers: [A102842](https://oeis.org/A102842). There are exactly $486$ insipid numbers less than $1000$. In fact, the insipid numbers are of density one, and the number of non-insipid numbers less than $r$ grows like $2r/\log r$ ([MR661693](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=661693), pointed out in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/336765/34538) of @verret).

Let call an index $d=\delta^2$ *insipid* if $\mathcal{TLJ}_{\delta}$ is the unique irreducible maximal subfactor planar algebras of index $d$. The insipid indices less than $4$ form the following set:

$$ \{4cos^2(\pi/n) \ | \ n \ge 3, \ n \neq 12, \ n \not \equiv 2 (\textrm{mod}\ 4) \}.$$

**Bonus question**: What is the full set of insipid indices?

*Remark*: By [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/132882/34538) of Noah Snyder, an insipid index must be less than $9$, because of the existence of infinite depth irreducible maximal subfactor planar algebras coming from $SU(3)$ at any index above $9$.

Let call an index $d \ge 4$ *finite-insipid* if an irreducible maximal subfactor planar algebra of index $d$ must be of infinite depth.

I will write a question about the finite-insipid indices later, any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: For those interested: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_algebra#Examples_and_results